# getting Error: request entity too large error when i send base64 image in mean js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload, meanjs, ng-file-upload

I am getting an error when I send base64 image in post call at server side.

I am using

```
var send_item = {
    lottreyId: data.data.id,
    title: item.title,
    merchant: item_val.merchant.id,
    value: item_val.value,
    description: item_val.description,
    image: base64
};
$http.post('/api/lottrey_item',
{
    send_item
}).then(function (data)
{
    console.log(data);
}, function (err)
{
    console.log(err);
    reject();
});
```

I can't use form data for send image, also, I can't use `ng-file-upload`.

When I use form data I can't get data in `req.data parameter`.

Can I use any alternative way to save an image in a temp folder in my project directory?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try 
`app.use(bodyParser.json({
    extended: true,
    limit: '50mb'
}));`

You ar using a JSON request, so you should specify the limit for `bodyParser.json`, not `bodyParser.urlencoded` .

Answer (score 0):

You should change the maximum request body size of `express-bodyparser` in your `/config/lib/express.js`. In the following line:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

Change it to (and adjust the limit value if needed):

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: '50mb'
}));
```

I can't test right now but it should do the trick.

Comment: not working getting the same error.
do you know when a request is form data then why I am not getting data at server side?
in same project other module working fine with form data and I create new module it's not working with form data